# Gmail filter criteria being ignored - always mark as important

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, priority-inbox

My Gmail Priority Mailbox was working pretty good until about a week ago.

I have a filter as per the following:

**Matches:** from:(sample@network.net) subject:(Sample Subject)
**Do this:** Apply label "MyLabel", Never send it to Spam, Mark it as important

**Problem:**

The last item in the filter (Mark it as important) is never being applied.  Even when I manually mark it as important, the next email matching the criteria is again ignored.  This filter has been in place for many months and used to work.  Now this problem has been going on for at least a week and for dozens of messages.

The matching portion of the filter is working since the labels are being applied... but they're never marked as important despite being told **"Always mark it as important**" in the filter's settings.

Is anyone else seeing this happen or know about this being a new Gmail bug?  Are there any workarounds?  Any information appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It's still happening and I've had no luck finding a link for reporting Gmail bugs to Google.  I read something at Google about reporting bugs and they said that one should just post their problem in the Google Groups forum.  That's useless it seems.

Just reported this on 8/9/11 at Noon CST to:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=inproduct&hl=en

I'll post any relevant follow-ups.

Comment: You can report it here: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=inproduct&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than a month of waiting and getting no answers at Google Groups from anyone at Google, as of today, it just started working again.

Another Gmail feature broken and fixed by Google without a word.

Comment: I have the same problem and this really doesn't answer it. Maybe if you didn't mark this as answered so others will see this as an open question and give us additional suggestions?

Comment: @studgeek, This is really the only correct answer as there is **nothing** at all you can do to solve this problem.  It was caused by Google and can only be fixed by Google.

Comment: @studgeek,   Marking this as answered has no negative impact on anyone's ability search, read, respond or post additional valid solutions.

Comment: just a clarification, it does have some impact. The question will no longer show up in "Unanswered". Some people (including myself) monitor that list for the tags they know.

Comment: @studgeek- no amount of complaining is going to change two facts.  1.  That it's my perogative to accept any answer I wish.  2.  The problem could not be solved by anyone other than Google.   I'm sorry you're unsatisfied by this.

Comment: My last comment wasn't a complaint, it was a clarification that marking something answered does affect a questions visibility. And I'm fine with you marking it answered, I was just a making a suggestion.